# Modify a line within a .txt file in python

Tags: python, str-replace, findandmodify

So I am trying to modify multiple lines within a text file that meet a criteria. 
The line will start with "Section", and then I will do some modifying to the line, then I would like to replace the old line with the new line. Currently my code looks line this but am getting the following error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'"

```
for f in glob.glob('*.svp'):
    print(f)
    with open(f,'r+') as ins:
        fileArray = []
        for line in ins:
            fileArray.append(line)
            if "Section" in line:
                lat = line[26:35]
                lineToKeep = line[:33] #Portion of line without lat.## lon, what will be amended
                latAmended = round(float(lat[7:])*0.6)
                latAmended = str(latAmended).zfill(2)
                lon = line[36:46]
                lonToKeep = lon[:-2]
                lonAmended = round(float(lon[8:])*0.6)
                lonAmended = str(lonAmended).zfill(2)
                goodStuff = lineToKeep + latAmended + ' '+ lonToKeep + lonAmended
                line = goodStuff
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are using the file path 'f' (a 'str' object) instead of the file object 'ins' itself. Changing the variable of the last line should do the trick:

```
            ins.write(line)
```